# Error in installing 'mvtnorm' and 'multcomp' package

Tags: r, installation

Trying to install the 'mvtnorm' and 'multcomp' packages in R-studio, which are dependencies for the 'coin' package I need to use.

```
 > install.packages('mvtnorm')        
 Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘mvtnorm’
 These will not be installed
```

The same error comes up when I try to install multcomp. Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: results of `sessionInfo()` please? and what CRAN mirror are you using?

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.2

Comment: Using whichever CRAN mirror is first on the CRAN mirror list. "Global CDN"?

Comment: Do you have R Tools installed?  I think that might be required on Windows to install packages from source. Link: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

Answer (score 1):

Updating your R version will fix this issue.

After updating your R version you can simply run `install.packages('mvtnorm', dep = TRUE)` and it will install the package for you.

You can alternatively download the package source ".tar.gz" file from here - https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvtnorm/index.html

then install the package by executing `install.packages(path_to_file, repos = NULL, type="source")` replacing the `path_to_file` with the path to the downloaded file.

Hope this helps